# Overpass Turbo print individual roadsegment lat long pairs

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have an Overpass Turbo query like this:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  way["highway"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out ids geom;
node(w);
way[highway](bn);
out geom;
>;
```

It is giving me the geometry output for each way like this:

```
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 27456387,
  "bounds": {
    "minlat": 48.7933753,
    "minlon": 2.3582882,
    "maxlat": 48.7944818,
    "maxlon": 2.3591516
  },
  "geometry": [
    { "lat": 48.7933753, "lon": 2.3591516 },
    { "lat": 48.7934014, "lon": 2.3591302 },
    { "lat": 48.7934354, "lon": 2.3591027 },
    { "lat": 48.7938331, "lon": 2.3587992 },
    { "lat": 48.7938713, "lon": 2.3587692 },
    { "lat": 48.7939427, "lon": 2.3587129 },
    { "lat": 48.7943657, "lon": 2.3583806 },
    { "lat": 48.7944220, "lon": 2.3583370 },
    { "lat": 48.7944818, "lon": 2.3582882 }
  ]
}
```

But instead of a linestring of geometry, I want to get each individual segment of the way where the output would be just the start point and end point of each individual segment:

```
"geometry": [
    { "lat": 48.7933753, "lon": 2.3591516 },
    { "lat": 48.7934014, "lon": 2.3591302 }
```

How can I change my overpass turbo query to output this type of result?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the geometry of OSM road segments? Are they often containing multiple Lat/Lng pairs in their geometry? (not just a single pair)

Comment: Ways in OSM are made up of multiple nodes, your way in question: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/27456387 is made of 9 nodes. In this case, they look aligned, so you could skip the middle ones but then you would miss out on the intersections, as the nodes are part of two ways. The nodes can also be signs/crossings/... so depending on your application you might need them. And if your road is curved, using just the start and end points would give you a different geometry.